# How to bind exit to a key?

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

When I am using `screen`, every time I use `kill`, it prompts a confirmation and ask me whether to really kill (which I really do after pressing so many keys). To get around this I type `exit` instead. But can I bind a key to it?

`bind key exit` does not work...

Comment: Where are you typing kill/exit?

Comment: Try using CTRL-D instead of exit.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for. Ae you talking about the `kill` command used to kill a process? Where/why do you need to type `exit`? Ctrl+D can be used to exit at various prompts, including most shells. And anyway, this smells like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @chipperyman573 I don't know why I tagged `screen` but it is automatically changed to `display`

Comment: @nitro2k01 It is corrected. See my comment above.

Comment: This site doesn't like duplicate tags and thought yo meant a computer display device. And I don't know what you're doing to invoke the kill command, but I would focus the active window and quit what is running in it, or press Ctrl+A,K,Y, which I don't think is overly many key presses. Is there any reason you cannot quit what's in the screen using normal methods, such as ctrl+C then ctrl+D to quit any shell, or similar?

Comment: Another handy "left-hander": Ctrl+Z to suspend a frozen application, then ctrl+D to quit it. Not sure if this will always work, but a good one to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is to bind a key to send "exit^M" to your shell session instead of producing kill command to the screen itself. Of course, this only works in case you have nothing else going on in the shell. For those occasions you might have to modify this example a bit, e.g. to send <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> followed by exit.

Add `bind ^K stuff "exit^M"` to your `~/.screenrc` and re-evaluate it by <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> `: source ~/.screenrc`.

After that you will be able to kill *shell sessions having an empty commmand line waiting* with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> (note the capital K there, you probably don't want to completely override the kill command of screen itself).